# How to get correct screen width (px) in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, width, samsung-galaxy

I have a physical device hooked up to my Android Studio - a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra 5G - SM-G988U. Everywhere I look online it lists the dimensions as 1440px x 3200px and 511 ppi.

However when I hook this phone up to android studio and I run my app I get the length and width measurements in Logcat (via the code below) and it returns **1080 x 2400**.

```
int screenWidth = 0;
int screenHeight = 0;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {

            screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

} else {

            WindowMetrics deviceWindowMetrics = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WindowManager.class).getMaximumWindowMetrics();
            screenWidth = deviceWindowMetrics.getBounds().width();
            screenHeight = deviceWindowMetrics.getBounds().height();

}

Log.d(TAG, "The screen width == " + screenWidth);
```

I can't figure out the reason why it prints 1080 as the width instead of 1440. The phone is a used phone I purchased online - the only reasoning I can come up with is that this phone is not really a Samsung Galaxy S20. All the other phones I'm using to test with return the expected width and height. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Some phones allow changing the resolution in settings

Comment: Thanks for that idea, I'm not use to android phones - I'm an iPhone user. I did find in the display menu where I could change the screen resolution. After I changed it to 3200 x 1440 WQHD+ and re-ran the app I still got the same results (Logcat reads the width as 1080).

Comment: I reset the phone and deleted the app and it worked. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I m not sure about this but try changing the resolution on your phone.
https://www.technobezz.com/how-to-change-screen-resolution-on-samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).